# Emulator crashing on button press in app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-emulator

I was following the Dev guide on Google's site: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

But whenever I press the button in my emulator the app crashes.
I tried it on my phone and I get the same result. Here is my code
The indentation is not working correctly on here
Main activity:

```
package com.example.rishubs.app;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Called when Button is pressed */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

My XML:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rishubs.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="14"
         android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
     </application>

</manifest>
```

My second activity

```
package com.example.rishubs.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get Message from intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(textView);
    }

}
```

Updated XML:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.rishubs.app"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="14"
         android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

     <application
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="DisplayMessageActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

`07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method send message(View) in the activity class com.example.rishubs.app.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3031)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: send message [class android.view.View]
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3024)
07-15 18:48:26.605: E/AndroidRuntime(1454):     ... 11 more`

Comment: Please, provide your LogCat output to see the error log.

Comment: Can you show your button's `onClickListener` and some logs as well, please.

Comment: Try to reconect your device again... this is not that log we were waiting for :P And, edit your question and put the logs there not as comment.

Comment: Logcat is blank. I am not sure how to use it, I am fairly new to this stuff :/

Comment: Got the logcat to work, updated with logs

Comment: @user67784 : Don't post your entire logcat. Simply start the app then click the button and look for the area of the logcat (normally highlighted in red) which shows the exception which is thrown then copy / paste just that part.

Comment: @user67784 : Edit your layout file and fix the `onClick` attribute for the `Button` - you have a space in between 'send' and 'message..."Could not find a method **send message(View)**". Also it's case sensitive so use `sendMessage`

Comment: The emulator itself crashes, not the app itself

Comment: @user67784 : Have you set the attribute to be exactly... `android:onClick="sendMessage"` (without the `(View)` part)?

Comment: @Squonk Yes, I have it exactly. `android:onClick="sendMessage"`

Comment: It worked! I changed the CPU type back to ARM, in x86 it crashes (weird?) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have add

```
<activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="DisplayMessageActivity">

    </activity>
```

replace it with

```
<activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity>
```

you have define your `Activity` twice..May be this is the issue of crash.

EDIT According to your new LogCat

seams like, conflict is  in your onclick methode name in `activity_main.xml`, in your `edit_message`, you have attribute like `android:onClick="send message"` replace it with `android:onClick="sendMessage"`

Comment: in your `activity_main.xml` do you have `EditText` with id `edit_message` ?

Comment: conflict in your onclick methode name in `activity_main`, in your `edit_message` attribute you have `android:onClick="send message"` replace it with `android:onClick="sendMessage"`

Comment: The emulator itself crashes, not the app itself

Comment: close the emulator and restart and retry :)

Comment: It worked! I changed the CPU type back to ARM, in x86 it crashes (weird?) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I see your mistake.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method send message(View) in the activity class com.example.rishubs.app.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
```

Go to your layout/activity_main.xml file and in your Button View make sure that

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

is there. According to LogCat you have android:onClick="send message" instead. So there is a unwanted space send + message and Message needs to have its first letter capitalized.

Basically you have named your method name sendMessage(View v) but have referenced it in the XML file as "send message". They are not the same :D

good luck

Answer (score -3):

Instead of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Try, this is in your MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Comment: MainActivity.this is not needed as intent is not fired from an Anonymous class, but from MainActivity's own method called sendMessage(View view)

Comment: The above poster mentioned this. You have not added your second activity to your xml. This is how you would add the DisplayMessageActivity to your xml: goto your xml, application tab, add, Activity, in the name browse and give it a second to load then select DisplayMessageActivity.

Comment: <activity android:name="DisplayMessageActivity">

        </activity>
Remove that.